# Question About numpy mean and handy average

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, average, grayscale

I am trying to implement **average with mathematic**, but my mathematic function average is not the same as the mean function

Executing the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img_path = r'Robert_Deniro.jpg'
imgArray = cv2.imread(img_path)


def ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage(ImgArray):
    gray_image = (ImgArray[:,:,2] + ImgArray[:,:,1] + ImgArray[:,:,0]) / 3
    return np.rint(gray_image).astype(np.uint8)


def ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage2(ImgArray):
    gray_image = np.mean(ImgArray, axis=2)

    return np.rint(gray_image).astype(np.uint8)


while True:
    cv2.imshow('1', ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage(imgArray))
    cv2.imshow('2', ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage2(imgArray))

    print(ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage(imgArray))
    print(ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage2(imgArray))

    if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage

function and

> ConvertToGrayScaleByAverage2

outputs are not same.but both result should be same !!

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't get it, you mentioned yourself, that your own *average* implementation is not the same as *mean*, so it is obvious why those functions don't result the same.

Comment: Overflow. You're performing the whole calculation using 8 bit unsigned integers.

Comment: i want to get same result of np.mean but without that function